# How would I add the PERSIST function to a ranking in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking, partition, persisted-column

How would I go about adding the PERSIST function to a ranking?

I plan on creating a view from this code and will be frequently running subqueries on it. So of course I don't want the ranking number to change based off of whatever subquery I run. I want it to be a normal, non-formula-like column.

```
    SELECT  a.player_id, a.full_name, a.first_name, a.last_name, d.[rank], 
    d.column3, a.tournament, c.column5, a.[year], a.[round], 
    a.score, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[round] + b.tournament_id + a.
    [year] ORDER BY a.score) AS round_leaderboard
    FROM            df1 AS a JOIN
    df2 AS b ON a.tournament = b.tournament JOIN
    df3 AS c ON c.[Event] = a.tournament
    LEFT JOIN df4 as d
    On a.player_id=d.player_id and a.[year]=d.[year]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a materialized view:

```
create view myview with schemabinding as
    SELECT  a.player_id, a.full_name, a.first_name, a.last_name, d.[rank], 
            d.column3, a.tournament, c.column5, a.[year], a.[round], 
            a.score,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[round] + b.tournament_id + a.[year] ORDER BY a.score) AS round_leaderboard
    FROM df1 a JOIN
         df2 b
         ON a.tournament = b.tournament JOIN
         df3 c
         ON c.[Event] = a.tournament LEFT JOIN
         df4 d
         On a.player_id = d.player_id and a.[year] = d.[year];

create index idx_myview_playerid on myview(playerid);
```

Materialized views are explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/materialized-view).